# Capture TraceMessage output

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm debugging an old closed-source library. I'm seeing lots of useful calls to [`TraceMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364139.aspx) with debug information when functions fail.

I've never heard of this "Event Tracing" that MSDN speaks of. Are there any tools that can capture these messages, or dump them to a log file? They seem to be meant for debugging, but I can't make any sense of the docs.

As a last resort, I plan to hook the function and write a custom dumper, but that is a lot of work. Surely there must be an easier way?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . I've worked with Microsoft's [Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) before and it's functionality is built upon event tracing (just a quick plug, I'm no fan of Microsoft, but that's a good tool for capturing IPv4 and IPv6 loopback traffic on Windows, among other things, if you need to do that). Not sure if Message Analyzer will display an event trace from any source.

Comment: `TraceMessage()` is part of the ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) API. Message Analyzer supports ETW sources, both from live events and saved log files.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! It seems it would work in most cases, unfortunately I'm stuck on a legacy system still running XP :( Message Analyzer can be installed on W7+, remote analysis since W8.1. It seems the command line tool `logman` should be able to do the same thing. Trying to get it running atm.

Comment: @toster-cx Did you ever figure out how to capture these events on less than W7?

Comment: @Casper no :( It may be possible to capture it with API monitor http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor